# Issue with array (Cannot implicitly Convert Type 'int' to 'int[]')

Tags: c#, arrays

I have been searching all night for a fix for a storage system for users inputs from a loop up to the limmit of 3 loop. i belive i have found it but as the title says i get the error Cannot implicitly Convert Type 'int' to 'int[]', on the console.readline for the user input? any suggestions on how i can solve this ?

Thank you In advnace.

```
            //Array For Ticket prices, sales and user input
            int[] TicketChoices = new int[3];

            //Ticket Types
            //ChildT = £1.50 = Child;
            //AdultT = £2.35 = Adult;
            //StudentT = £1.99 = Student;

            //Film      Certificate     Seats   Screen
            //Jaws          12A          15       1
            //The Exorcist  18           33       2

            cw("Hello Current tickets are:");

            for (int I = 0; I < 3; I++)

                {
                    cw("ID (1) Child, £1.50");
                    cw("ID:(2) Adult, £2,35");
                    cw("ID:(3) Student £1.99");
                    cw("");
                    cw("Please Select Which ticket you would like to input By Entering it's id Number");
                    cw("input Must be between 1-3 for it to be vaild.");
                    TicketChoices = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think you are trying to do:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //Array For Ticket prices, sales and user input
        var ticketChoices = new int[3];

        //Ticket Types
        //ChildT = £1.50 = Child;
        //AdultT = £2.35 = Adult;
        //StudentT = £1.99 = Student;

        //Film      Certificate     Seats   Screen
        //Jaws          12A          15       1
        //The Exorcist  18           33       2

        Console.WriteLine("Hello Current tickets are:");

        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("ID (1) Child, £1.50");
            Console.WriteLine("ID:(2) Adult, £2,35");
            Console.WriteLine("ID:(3) Student £1.99");
            Console.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine("Please Select Which ticket you would like to input By Entering it's id Number");
            Console.WriteLine("input Must be between 1-3 for it to be vaild.");
            var valid = false;
            while (!valid)
            {
                var input = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(input, out var ticketNumber))
                {
                    if (ticketNumber >= 0 && ticketNumber <= 3)
                    {
                        valid = true; 
                    }
                }

                if (valid)
                {
                    ticketChoices[i] = ticketNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a value between 1 and 3");
                }
            }
        }

        // Print the results 
        Console.WriteLine("You entered:");
        foreach (var ticketChoice in ticketChoices)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ticketChoice);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] TicketChoices = new int[3];
```

`TicketChoices` is not an `int` its an array of `int`

```
TicketChoices = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Maybe something like this instead

```
var choice = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Also if you take input form a user don't, trust them to get it right

Use [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2) Instead

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
>   integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
>   succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

`int.Parse` returns a single integer. So you are trying to set `TicketChoices` (an array) to a single integer. That won't work.

You can set the *first* integer in your array to the output of `int.Parse`, if that's what you want:

```
TicketChoices[0] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```